# What does "Fun corner" mean?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

> In this fun corner, I would like to share with you some of my passions, inspirations and also where I get my kicks from.

In the above text what does "fun corner" mean?
Is it an English expression?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It's a metaphorical "corner" of the website, like a "corner" of a room: an area away from the center, where secondary activities are carried out.

(It may help to understand that many US grade-school classrooms are laid out with different "activity stations" -- for insance, a computer corner, a science corner, an art corner, and so forth.)

In this case, the "corner" is the area the author has reserved for "fun"--for posts that are not central to the site's primary activities but are valued just because they're entertaining or interesting in themselves.

Comment: As an aside, it can also refer to the corner of a [boxing ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boxing_ring). Each contestant has their "corner" of the area that they return to between rounds. Saying "I'm in your corner" means you are on the same team, for example.